# Use chacha20-poly1305 symmectric algorithm for HTTPS in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, aes, tls1.2

Does anyone know if it's possible to use a cipher suite with chacha20, for example TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 in a desktop client written in .NET (v4.6.2) running on Windows 10?

My scenario is that I have a client that needs to talk to a server over TLS, where the server runs on an embedded device, which would benefit a lot, performance wise, if I could use chacha20 instead of AES.

I'm hoping to be able to use the existing HttpClient or WebClient classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the .NET Framework, the built-in support for HTTP (and by extension TLS) is handled by `ServicePoint` class. You can configure basic parameters like the TLS versions to support via the `ServicePointManager` class, but this class doesn't offer any extension points for supplying a custom algorithm.

The Framework delegates to Windows to perform TLS handshakes, including the supported algorithms. If Windows were to support chacha20, you might have a better chance at this, but to my knowledge it does not.

The only way I could consider achieving this now would be to provide a custom implementation of [`HttpMessageHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpmessagehandler(v=vs.118).aspx) which has its own transport implementation around a naked socket.